# How did the SysRandom work on Palm Pilot SDK 3.5?

Tags: palm

I'm looking to port an old game I wrote for the Palm Pilot that relied on the `SysRandom` function with a predefined game seed. A player could enter a "seed" and the sequence of tiles would be deterministic. So if I can recreate the `SysRandom` function in another language (JavaScript is my jam, but I can probably port C and most other languages if pushed) then I can retain all the old player's high scores from the original game.

I'm not even sure where to start searching though!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Palm `SysRandom` RNG was reverse-engineered by Ian Goldberg and documented *e.g.* in [this Password Generator exploit](https://vulners.com/exploitdb/EDB-ID:20746):

```
/* The PalmOS SysRandom() RNG. */

static unsigned int multiplier = 22695477;
static unsigned int _seed = 0;

short palm_rand (unsigned int new_seed)
{
  if (new_seed)
    _seed = new_seed;
  
  _seed = (_seed * multiplier) + 1;
  return (short)  ((_seed >> 16)  & 0x7fff);
}
```

(See also [the corresponding SecurityTracker entry](https://securitytracker.com/id/1001292) which provides Thomas Roessler’s full message. This RNG is also briefly described in [Peter Gutmann’s *Cryptographic Security Architecture: Design and Verification*](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387953878).)

Comment: Hmm, the same multiplier as Borland C's [LCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#Parameters_in_common_use)

Comment: Interesting. So the first random number (assuming it is not reseeded) is always zero.

Comment: If you happen to find the sources of POSE (the Palm OS Emulator) you might see some "real" source code. I remember that I once found the source of the CRC funtions.

Comment: @thebusybee I had checked, without much hope because I expected `SysRandom` to be implemented in the ROMs, and it is (so no source code in POSE).

Comment: (The POSE source code if still available [from SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pose/).)

Comment: Aargh, s/if/is/...